# systemd user service doesn't autorun on user login

Tags: debian, systemd

I have Debian Jessie and connect to it by ssh. I want to autostart shell command on user login by systemd.

I've create a simple systemd service `~/.config/systemd/user/foo.service` witch contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=Systemd autostart test
Wants=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 123 >> /home/user/there;"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've enable it by systemctl

```
systemctl --user enable foo
```

I've created success message container

```
touch ~/there
```

and after reboot and login (by ssh) `~/there` file is empty.

When I use it manually

```
systemctl --user restart foo
```

it works.

What am I missing?

Comment: `systemd` normally does not allow ordinary users to start system services. Why not using `.profile` ?

Comment: @Froggiz very late reply, but: `systemd` doesn't allow ordinary users to start system services, yes. But as is clear in the question, the user is calling `systemctl --user`, which is for user services, not system ones.

Answer (score 10):

By default, users cannot set user services to run at boot time. The admin must enable this on an individual basis for each user.

```
sudo loginctl enable-linger <username>
```

From the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html):

> Enable/disable user lingering for one or more users. If enabled for a specific user, a user manager is spawned for the user at boot and kept around after logouts. This allows users who are not logged in to run long-running services. Takes one or more user names or numeric UIDs as argument. If no argument is specified, enables/disables lingering for the user of the session of the caller.

You also need to [set the correct target for WantedBy=](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251211/20805) as Climenty explained in [another answer](https://serverfault.com/a/802302/126632). The `multi-user.target` does not exist for user services; by default there is only `default.target`.

```
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[Install]    
WantedBy=default.target
```